# Deploying Program that uses MS Access without installing MS Access to that PC

Tags: ms-access, interop

As the title says, can I deploy my compiled program that uses MS Access without ever installing MS Office let alone MSAccess in that terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If your program was built IN Access it requires Access. If it was built in, say .NET (or using an appropriate driver), all that is required to access it is the MDB file itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your program must only access microsoft access files, you can do it.
For example, if you develop an application in c # you can access file access via ODBC, OLEDB.

Other languages ​​can always access files Access via ODBC or specific libraries, an example is Java.

If your program requires functions that reside only in MSAcces (eg calls functions accessible with VB or VBScript) you will be forced to distribute them together

If you could be more clear

Comment: I am using Powerbuilder. Do I need a certain DLL to be included or do  need to install an ODBC Driver / Library in that machine? I used a DSNLESS Profile String.

Comment: I used Powerbuilder a lot of time ago win95 to release app on CD at that time you need to follow this instructions http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pbarc/pbu0500e/pbug/@Generic__BookTextView/41108;hf=0

I think in your situation that you don't need to release acces

Comment: @Sid Even with a **DSN Less** string, the machine needs to have the correct drivers installed to use it.

Comment: @MattDonnan yes, but isnt installing the drivers the same as putting the dll in the same folder of the executable?

Comment: @Sid I'm not sure if that will work in this case, never tried to be honest, I always go with installing the drivers.